# CSS display element in one line with nowrap

Tags: css, nowrap

I now width of my `div`, but i don't know height of my childrens `button` and `ins` tag.
The ins tag has nowrap.

I would like display `button` in one line with `ins` tag.

```
div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

button {
}

ins {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

There is my code, but now is `ins` below `button`: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZrJM/
I can't use height of `div`.

How display button and ins in one line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move the `white-space:nowrap` from `ins` to `div`. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZrJM/1/)

```
div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
     white-space: nowrap;
}
```